# OCaml-Wodi: Installing Lablgtk2?

Tags: user-interface, gtk, ocaml, godi, lablgtk

I have been trying to install lablgtk2 on my wodi32 cygwin since the package environment did not initially come with lablgtk (just lablgtk).

I followed these directions to do it manually myself:

```
2) Install lablgtk2 binaries and scripts inside the OCaml distribution
     bin/*                   -> bin
     lib/site-lib/lablgtk2   -> lib/site-lib/lablgtk2
   Then edit lib/ld.conf, and add the line
     \lib\site-lib\lablgtk2

3) If your distribution is newer than 4.00.0, go to the
   lib/site-lib/lablgtk2 directory and execute

        ocaml build.ml
```

But it doesn't seem to be working right.  Is there a Wodi method of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the root folder of your cygwin-installation is a link called "Wodi32 Package Manager.lnk". Click on it (from Windows Explorer) to start the GUI for package installation. Or run /opt/wodi32/gui/bin/gui.exe from inside cygwin (btw: the gui was written with the package you are looking for :) )

The package ist called (godi-)lablgtk2. ( lablgtk3 isn't published yet, and lablgtk1 is obselete). godi-lablgtk2 supports nearly all bindings, including gnomecanvas, gktspell, gtksourceview2, etc.

Comment: haha yeah I noticed that, the gui itself was written using lablgtk2 yet lablgtk2 itself wasn't included in the initial wodi package...

Comment: Rafix, please see the following follow-up post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266275/ocaml-wodi-part-2-compiling-using-what-was-installed.  If you could provide any insight that would be much appreciated, as there is still a problem with the linking of the appropriate lablgtk2 modules even the Package Manager succesffully.